# A tree has at most one perfect matching (proof verification)

Tags: graph-theory, solution-verification, trees, matching-theory

Question: Let $T$ be a tree, prove that **at most** $1$ perfect matching exists in $T$

My Proof:

Let $M$ and $M'$ be perfect matches in the tree $T = (V,E)$
And let $G$ be a graph on the vertex set $V$ and edges set: $M \cup M'$. Because $M$ and $M'$ cover all the vertices, each component of that graph $G$ is an isolated vertex (which is in $M$ **and** $M'$) or it is a cycle. Because $T$ is a tree, it does not have cycles and thus we conclude that $M = M'$

I would appreciate if you could tell me if I am wrong/right and tell me where should I fix that proof. Thank you!

Comment: Small misnomer: I'm sure you meant to take the symmetric difference in the second line of your proof rather than the union of $M$ and $M'$. Additionally, I'd maybe add another sentence saying exactly why having all vertices of the proposed graph $G$ being isolated means that $M$ and $M'$ are the same. Other than the these minor things your proof is fine.

Comment: @Paralyzed_by_Time what should I say about the part that each vertex is isolated? Thank you!

Comment: Maybe that a match is a set o *edges* and if each vertex is isolated, we have no edges and thus it is true (null case)

Comment: @Paralyzed_by_Time please consider turning your comment into an answer, so that it can be accepted.